# How to use ScreenWidth in other classes?

Tags: c#, xna

This is the code I'm using to get the variable containing the `screenHeight`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    Ball pall;
    MinuPad playerPad;
    public int screenWidth;
    public int screenHeight;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        screenWidth = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
        screenHeight = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
```

But I can't use the variable in different classes. For example I have a class called `Ball.cs` where I also need to use information about `screenWidth` and `screenHeight`.

When I try to use the same `GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width` it gives me :

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 
'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.get'
```

My Question : Why can't I use `GraphicsDevice.Viewport` in other classes? What should I do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you can't access it is because the instance of the class Ball is simply not aware of the Viewport. You can fix this with a few options, the main being pass the `Viewport` to the constructor of your ball, e.g:

```
public class Ball
{

    Viewport viewport;

    // ... 

    public Ball(int stuff, Viewport viewport)
    {
         this.viewport = viewport;

         // ...
    }
}
```

Create the instance of the ball within the `Game1` class with something along the lines of:

```
Ball ball = new Ball(42, GraphicsDevice.Viewport);
```

You could then simply do `viewport.Height` from within Ball.cs.

If you wanted something more global so that you could use the height/width *anywhere* then you could make a static viewport in Game1 (`public static Viewport`) and setting `Viewport` in the `Initialise()`/`LoadContent()` method; you'd access this with `Game1.Viewport`. Personally I don't like this way because it seems 'hacker-ish' but it gets the job done.. although saying that, I usually have a static random class in my game class :)!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% familiar with C#, but I think you're missing an import statement at the top.

Try including the line:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics
```

...at the top of `Ball.cs`.

I'm guessing that if you check your main file, you'll see that line (and similar ones) at the top of the file.

If you check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197329.aspx) for `GraphicsDevice`, you'll see it lives in the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my bad that I left it out.. I had it

Comment: In that case, could you post the code in `Ball.cs` for comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with XNA, but my guess is that `GraphicsDevice` is a member of the base class `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game`. You will not be able to access it from a class which is not derived from `Game`.

Again, not familiar with XNA, but if your `Ball` class has access to an instance of your `Game1` class, then it should be able to access the `screenWidth` field:

```
public class Ball
{
    Game1 _game;
    public Ball(Game1 game){_game = game;}
    private void UseScreenWidth(){
        // Do something with _game.screenWidth;
    }
}
```